# Can't use updated variables in handle function

Tags: plugins, php, hooks

I have some problem with the [wp-background-processing](https://github.com/deliciousbrains/wp-background-processing) that's when I change the `$url` in another file using `$this->process_single->url('https://anotherexample.com');` the url won't update in handle function :/ but when I echo it in dispatch, it shows the updated url

here is my `class-example-request.php` file:

```php
<?php

class WP_Example_Request extends WP_Async_Request {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $action = 'example_request';
    protected $url = "https://example.com";

    public function url($url){
        $this->url = $url;
        return $this;
    }

    public function get_url(){
        return $this->url;
    }

    public function handle() {
        $response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $this->get_url() ) );//here, the url won't update!
    }

    public function dispatch() {
        $url  = add_query_arg( $this->get_query_args(), $this->get_query_url() );
        $args = $this->get_post_args();
        echo $this->get_url(); // this echos the updated url
        return wp_remote_post( esc_url_raw( $url ), $args );
    }
}
```

any ideas?

update:

This is my main plugin file

```php
<?php
/* 
Plugin info...
*/
class Example_Background_Processing {
    protected $process_single;
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'init' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', array($this, 'add_to_cart_callback'), 10, 2);
        
    }


    public function init() {
        
        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'async-requests/class-example-request.php';
        
        $this->process_single = new WP_Example_Request();
    }
    
    public function add_to_cart_callback($cart_item_data, $productId){
        $this->process_single->url('https://httpbin.org/anything');

        $this->process_single->data( array() );
        $this->process_single->dispatch();
    }

}
new Example_Background_Processing();
```

Comment: When are you updating the URL? If you're updating the URL in a separate request then the URL isn't going to be updated for subsequent requests. If you want the change to be persistent you need to write it to and read it from the database.

Comment: I've changed it before I called the `dispatch` function in another file.

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I've updated the question

Comment: Is there a reason you’re redefining the dispatch method? That’s not how this library is supposed to be used, going off the documentation anyway. The way you’ve written it it’s not async anymore.

Comment: no I've redefined it to see if the `$this->url` changed or not. and it changes in dispatch but not in handle

Comment: We're back at my original comment. If the URL is changed in one request it will not be changed in subsequent requests. When you dispatch a task you are running that task in a separate request, so the URL will not be changed. Class properties are not persistent across requests. As documented, for any data you want to use in your async handler you need to define it with the `->data()` method and then access the value from `$_POST` in the `handle()` method. This takes care of writing the value to the database and passing it to the next request for you.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Holy shit that worked! you are my hero!

Comment: Have you asked this over at https://github.com/deliciousbrains/wp-background-processing? If you've found the solution you should post it as an answer rather than a comment

Comment: Yeah, I've asked it there too, I will post the answer here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A huge thanks to @JacobPeattie

We should pass the url to `data` function and retrieve it using `_POST`

so the main file will be:

```php
<?php
/* 
Plugin info...
*/
class Example_Background_Processing {
    protected $process_single;
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'init' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', array($this, 'add_to_cart_callback'), 10, 2);
        
    }


    public function init() {
        
        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'async-requests/class-example-request.php';
        
        $this->process_single = new WP_Example_Request();
    }
    
    public function add_to_cart_callback($cart_item_data, $productId){

        $this->process_single->data( array('url'=>'https://httpbin.org/anything') )->dispatch();
    }

}
new Example_Background_Processing();
```

and the `class-example-request.php` file will be:

```php
<?php

class WP_Example_Request extends WP_Async_Request {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $action = 'example_request';

    public function handle() {
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        $response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url );
    }

}
```

if the request has payloads, we could pass it like the url.

@JacobPeattie feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the method use for the variable $url

- public - the property or method can be accessed from everywhere. This
  is default
- protected - the property or method can be accessed within the class
  and by classes derived from that class
- private - the property or method can ONLY be accessed within the
  class

In your case your script is not allowed to modify a protected variable.
Change it to public.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I used functions to change the `protected` values and that's a convenient way, but I've changed them to `public` and nothing has changed. keep in mind that the `$url` shows correctly when I echo it on `dispatch` function!